# Ближайшее число

Tags: python

Для каждого из K чисел найдите ближайшее к нему число в отсортированном массиве.

Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных содержатся числа N и K (0<N,K<100001). Во второй строке задаются N чисел первого массива, отсортированного по неубыванию, а в третьей строке — K чисел второго массива. Каждое число в обоих массивах по модулю не превосходит 2⋅10^9.

Выходные данные

Для каждого из K чисел выведите в отдельную строку число из первого массива, наиболее близкое к данному. Если таких несколько, выведите меньшее из них.

Ограничение: работа программы не более 3 сек.

```
N, K = map(int, input().split())
P = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
V = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = []


for i in range(len(a)):
if a[i] < n:
find_num = -find_num
else:
find_num = find_num + 0
if a[i] >= n and a[i] - n <= find_num - n:
find_num = a[i]
elif a[i] <= n and find_num - n <= a[i] - n:
find_num = a[i]


print(P)
```

Comment: Вы забыли написать вопрос

Comment: Какие ошибки я допустил?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что вы допустили какие-то ошибки?

Comment: При вводе
5 5
1 3 5 7 9 
2 4 8 1 6 
должно выходить
1 3 7 1 5, а выводит 1 3 5 7 9

Comment: В коде написано вывести первый массив `print(P)` вот поэтому он и выводится.